# How can I fix PreEmptive Dotfuscator (VS2013)?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dotfuscator

I have Visual Studio 2013 which included "PreEmptive Dotfuscator and Analytics".

It's always worked fine for me until recently.
Suddenly it will not open from Visual Studio, icon or commandline.
Even when I manually open it, it does not show up in the task manager.

It simply does nothing.

There's nothing in the Event Viewer logs.
Visual Studio shows no error.
Basically, I can't even begin to find the problem.

I tried to find a download to attempt to reinstall it but all I've seen on the website for this version is that it's included in VS2013.

There's other sites in search results which claim to have the installer but none I trust.

Has anyone had this issue in the past?

It's Visual Studio 2013 Professional on Windows 8.1.

I'm not sure how to address this so I would greatly appreciate any possible input.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try uninstalling, wiping the settings, and reinstalling. Dotfuscator Community Edition is uninstallable via the Windows control panel. Once uninstalled, delete `%LOCALAPPDATA%\PreEmptive Solutions`. You may be able to reinstall it as a component via the Visual Studio installer. If not, it is actually a standalone installer, so if you have a Visual Studio disc or .iso, it will be in `\packages\Dotfuscator`.

Comment: I should have added that I did check the control panel but it is not listed there. However I failed to think about the iso. Good call, thanks. I'll try that out.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Nathan but sadly even after reinstalling, it still does not open at all. If anyone else sees this and has ideas please let me know. Meanwhile I'm "whacking" at it in random ways and I'll post back if I resolve it.

Comment: You might also try uninstalling, deleting `%LOCALAPPDATA%\PreEmptive Solutions`, then reinstalling.

Comment: You saved me @nathan! I am so amazed I didn't think of that but very glad you did. If you put that as an answer I'll mark it accepted. For anyone else - I only needed to delete it the folder, I did not need to reinstall.

Comment: I added the extra note into the answer above

Comment: Thanks again. Marked